# CollectionView, two buttons cant communicate - Swift 4

Tags: swift, xcode, uibutton, uicollectionview, swift4

I have a collectionView which has two buttons. CollectionView is being created according to an array, first button is being renamed accordingly. But the second button is always going to be a share button.

For each CollectionviewCell, for share button, I need to reach and read the current title of the renaming first button(it has an .mp3 file named exactly as the title of the button in the project). So that I can share that mp3 file according to the first button's title. But I cannot reach out for it. Any idea how I can solve this??

I cannot drop outlets of buttons to ViewController, since they are in a repeating content.

First play button :

```
@IBAction func buttonPlayTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let musicFile = Bundle.main.path(forResource: sender.currentTitle!, ofType: "mp3")

    do{
        try soundPlay = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL (fileURLWithPath: musicFile!))
    }
    catch {
        print(error)
    }
    soundPlay.play()
}
```

Share button :

```
@IBAction func shareTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    // I need to access the main button's title for 'forResource' in order to share that exact mp3 file
    let activityItemTwo = URL.init(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "", ofType: "mp3")!)

    let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [activityItemTwo],applicationActivities: nil)
    activityVC.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view

    self.present(activityVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

thats how I rename my first button while CollectionViewCells are loading:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! myCell
    cell.myVoiceButton.setTitle(soundNames[indexPath.row], for: .normal)

    return cell
}
```

Comment: Can you show how you rename your button.If that rename text is in your array you can access from it

Comment: I have updated my post, buttons are being renamed from soundNames array, but how can I imply for share button action to know for which collectionviewcell's first button's name should be fetched from soundNames array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need you set

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! myCell
cell.myVoiceButton.setTitle(soundNames[indexPath.row], for: .normal)
cell.yourhareBtn.tag = indexPath.row
return cell
 }
```

now replace your share tapped method by

```
 @IBAction func shareTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    //cast into  uibutton to access its property
    let button  = sender as? UIButton
    // safly access button
    guard let currentButton = button else {return}
    // get title
    let title = soundNames[currentButton.tag]
    let activityItemTwo = URL.init(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "", ofType: "mp3")!)

    let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [activityItemTwo],applicationActivities: nil)
    activityVC.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view

    self.present(activityVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

But remember this works only when you are not deleting or adding data.Because getting view or button by tag is not a good idea.But it should work for you.Let me know if you have any problem